# Ayuda con un JOINS en 2 tablas en MySQLi en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, join

les comento he leido varias veces el blog de https://www.vichaunter.org/desarrollo-web/joins-mysql-bien-explicado-lo-necesitas-saber

pero no logro implementar un JOINS en mi proyecto, lo que tengo hasta el momento me funciona perfecto pero estoy haciendo 2 o 3 query y la idea es optimizar las consultas a mi base de datos por lógicas razones.

**LO QUE TENGO**

```
Query 1
SELECT * FROM pagos  WHERE user = '$usua' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end

Query 2
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$rowUser'
```

Usando estos 2 Query recupero la informacion contenida por medio de un `mysqli_fetch_assoc` y he logrado que funcione mi proyecto, pero me gustaría aprender a implementar un JOINS en mi query para darle practicidad con el uso de dinamismos con el uso de un `LIKE '%$busqueda%'` como lo he hecho en otros de mis query que he implementado una busqueda asi:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
             WHERE (idusuario LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR
                    nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR
                    email LIKE '%$busqueda%') 
             AND user_type = '$user_tipo'
             ORDER BY id
             DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end
```

**Lo que Necesito**
Que el query me haga un SELECT y con el dato user de la tabla PEDIDO se recupere el nombre de la tabla USERS y que por medio de un `mysqli_fetch_array` pueda recuperar dicho dato dejo a continuación la estructura de mis 2 tablas

```
    TABLA USER
-id
-idusuario
-nombre
-usernameÍndice
-email
-tlf
-cel
-direccion

TABLA PEDIDO
-id
-user
-monto
-concepto
-mes_de_pago
-afiliacion
-banco_origen
-banco_destino

En la tabla PEDIDO user = idusuario de la tabla USERS
```

Con la ayuda de ustedes intente hacerlo yo solo pero no lo logre, voy a colocar la function completa en la que estoy trabajando

```
<?php
function lista_pagos_mes(){
    global $db, $usua, $mes, $limit_end;

  $url = basename($_SERVER ["PHP_SELF"]);

  if (isset($_REQUEST['busqueda'])) {
    $busqueda = strtolower($_REQUEST['busqueda']);
  } else {
    $busqueda = "";
  }


    if (isset($_GET['mes']))
        $ini=$_GET['mes'];
    else
        $ini=1;
        $init = ($ini-1) * $limit_end;


        if (isAdmin()) {

          if (empty($busqueda)) {
            $busqueda = "";
            $countmes="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagos WHERE status_pago = 'PENDIENTE'";
            $querymes = "SELECT * FROM pagos WHERE status_pago = 'PENDIENTE' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
            $resultmes = mysqli_query($db, $querymes);
            $rowmes =  mysqli_num_rows($resultmes);

            $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar';
          } else {
            $countmes="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagos WHERE status_pago = 'PENDIENTE' AND (user LIKE '%$busqueda%')";
            $querymes = "SELECT * FROM pagos WHERE status_pago = 'PENDIENTE'  AND (user LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
            $resultmes = mysqli_query($db, $querymes);
            $rowmes =  mysqli_num_rows($resultmes);

            $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar';

          }

        } else {

            $countmes="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pagos WHERE user = '$usua'";
            $querymes = "SELECT * FROM pagos  WHERE user = '$usua' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
            $resultmes = mysqli_query($db, $querymes);
            $rowmes =  mysqli_num_rows($resultmes);

            $mensaje  = 'No hay datos que Mostrar del usuario ' .$_SESSION['user']['username'];


        }

/* querys */


    if (!$rowmes){

    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" >';
    echo '<h3>';
    echo $mensaje; 
    //unset($_SESSION['successmes']);
    echo '</h3>';
    echo '</div>';

    } else {
        $num = $db->query($countmes);
        $x = $num->fetch_array();
        $total = ceil($x[0]/$limit_end);

        if (isAdmin()){


    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo '<table id="tabla1" class="table table-bordered table-hover stacktable">
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>ID</th> 
     <th>Usuario</th>
     <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Fecha de Pago </th>
      <th>Monto / Mes Pagado</th>
      <th>Nro Transf / CI</th>
      <th>Desde / Hasta</th>
      <th>Accion</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>';

     $c = $db->query($querymes);
     while($rowmes = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
      $date = date_create($rowmes['fecha_pago']);
      $fecha = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
      $fecha_pago = $fecha;
      $rowUser = $rowmes['user'];
      $rowid = $rowmes['id'];

      $sql_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$rowUser' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
      $resultado_user = mysqli_query($db,$sql_user);
    $row_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_user);
    $rowNombre = $row_user['nombre'];
      $link_aprobar_mes = '<form autocomplete="off" class="was-validated" method="post" action= "mensualidades.php?id='.$rowid.'&user='.$rowUser.'"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="aprobar_pago_btn">Aprobar</button> </form>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$rowid.'</td>
       <td>'.$rowUser.'</td>
       <td>'.$rowNombre.'</td>
       <td>'.$fecha_pago .'</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['monto'].' BsS / '.$rowmes['mes_de_pago']. '</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['nro_transf'] . ' / '.$rowmes['ci_nro_cuenta'].'</td>
       <td>'.$rowmes['banco_origen'].' / '.$rowmes['banco_destino'] .'</td>
       <td>'.$link_aprobar_mes .'</td>
      </tr>';
      } 
      echo '</tbody></table>';


        }
        else
        // SI NO ES ADMIN
?>
```

Así como lo tengo solo me permite filtrar los resultados según lo que se desee buscar pero asi como esta funciona solo si se efectúa una búsqueda del numero de cliente y mi idea es que si se busca un nombre también lo haga..!

Comment: No entendí bien lo que necesitas pero el join seria algo así:

`SELECT *.p , *.u  FROM pagos p  
inner join  USER u on p.user = u.idusuario
WHERE u.username = '$rowUser' and
p.user = '$usua'`

Comment: Gracias por tu gentil y rapida respuesta, ahorita uso `SELECT * FROM pagos  WHERE user = '$usua' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $init, $limit_end` y con un `fetch_array` recupero lo que necesito, me gustaria recuperar el nombre del usuario que esta en otra tabla de nombre USERS y no se si con el uso de un joins pueda obtener el resultado que espero ejemplo: como esta yo recupero `$rowmes['id'] $rowmes['user'], $rowmes['monto']` pero para recuperar el nombre de este usuario lo estoy haciendo con un segundo query 
lo que me gustaria hacer es que yo pueda recuperar el nombre con `$rowmes['nombre']`

Comment: Dices que no logras implementar el join, pero pon lo que has podido hacer con join para decirte en que está mal? qué error da?

Comment: con el join que te pase recuperas todos los campos de la tabla user, incluido nombre. Como dice @Sr1871 estaria bueno que pongas el join implementado.

Comment: Voy a empezar de cero, ya que al implementar el joins simplemente no me da resultados cuando efectuo la busqueda..! Asi como esta mi function PHP efectua la busqueda solo si el dato buscado coincide con el numero de cliente.! a ver si alguno puede sacarme de esta gran duda, de seguro para alguno de ustedes es mas sencillo, yo tengo como casi una semana intentando y es que no comprendo muy bien el funcionamiento del JOINS estoy tapado en eso.. igual estoy metiendome un puñal con varios blogs que explican el uso de los JOINS

Comment: Modifique mi enunciado a ver si me explico mejor.

Answer (score 0):

A fin ahora comprendo el uso de JOIN en MYSQL estaba algo perdido, pero he solucionado usando el siguiente query

basandome en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SELECT nombre_columna
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB
ON tableA.nombre_columna=tableB.nombre_columna
```

He re escrito mi query asi:

```
$querymes = "SELECT * FROM pagos
        INNER JOIN users
        ON pagos.user=users.idusuario
         WHERE status_pago = 'PENDIENTE'  AND (user LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%') ORDER BY fecha_pago ASC LIMIT $init, $limit_end";
```

> Al combinar y/o unir los registros de más de una tablas (pueden ser dos o más tablas). La cláusula ON se utiliza para que coincida con los registros en dos tablas o más a través de una columna con un valor en común entre las tablas que se van a unir, basándose en el valor de la columna id. El uso de INNER JOIN combina una unión interior permite filas de cualquiera de las tablas aparezcan en el resultado si y sólo si ambas tablas cumplen las condiciones especificadas en la cláusula ON, para obtener resultados relacionado entre sí en una consulta de php y mysql que necesitamos en nuestro proyectos web.